# ASP.NET WebAPI with HawkNet authentication and multiple users

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, hmac

I am writing an web based application that needs to expose an API to a Windows Forms client. I'm using ASP.Net WebAPI v2, and because I cannot make use of SSL (too expensive for the small scale project it is), I stumbled upon HawkNet and this looks like the best option for securing the communication between my client and server (which I both control).

However, one things gets me confused with the HawkNet configuration on the server side: all the examples shown on sites and blogs, show a hardcoded handler in the WebApiConfig register method like this:

```
var handler = new HawkMessageHandler(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config),
         (id) =>
         {
             return Task.FromResult(new HawkCredential
             {
                 Id = "dh37fgj492je",
                 Key = "werxhqb98rpaxn39848xrunpaw3489ruxnpa98w4rxn",
                 Algorithm = "sha256",
                 User = "steve"
             });
         }, 60, true);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",

            constraints: null,
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            handler: handler
        );
```

However, in my scenario, the Windows Forms client will be used by different users, on different laptops, and each user needs to be able to "log in" from this WinForms app in order to use the web API. If I understand correctly, I need to maintain a "key" and "id" like above for each user (can do that on the server in the database), and the client must also know this key (I guess the key could be something like hashing the username and password combo, so it can be built in the client and on the server without ever needing to pass it on the wire).

But how do I configure that on the server ? In order words, how do I make those values (username, key and id) in the HawkMessageHandler on the server dynamic ?

Or am I totally missing the point here ?

Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found it.

Can use the (id) parameter to pass it onto another function which can then look it up in the database using this id, and return a hawkcredential object